# Support needed for Django app deployment on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I have an app I'd like to deploy on Heroku. Not finished yet but it's now a requirement from my teacher.
I created an account and app on heroku and use the GitHub deployment method but when I click on deploy branch I have the following type of error:

```
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_0f3c3e792cd2015b5d316aad8cf28d6c/static'
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected,
```

Can you help me understand the error and solve it?

I'd like to use this deployment method if possible as I am very much a begginer in git too and I'd like to avoid doing it with CLI for now.

Thanks,

Edit: As required Requirements.txt pasted:

```
asgiref==3.2.3
Brotli==1.0.7
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.3
django-crispy-forms==1.9.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.9
psycopg2==2.8.5
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.23.0
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
urllib3==1.25.9
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

Comment: can you paste your requirements.txt

Comment: Added as needed :)

Comment: There is some version issue dude. Please fix your requirements.txt file

Comment: Hi, 
Do you have any resources where I could learn to do it correctly?

Comment: Yeah, now I get it, silly me, I saved the wrong file as requirements. :/

Comment: yes, that was the issue I was addressing. Anyways here is the link
(https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/09/how-to-deploy-django-applications-on-heroku.html)

Comment: Thanks, requirements updated in my post as well. It generated a new error :
Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
Post updated completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is the state of your settings but make sure your static urls are all created in **settings.py**. Specially the **STATICFILES_DIRS** which will set a place to collect the statics for production.

Please follow this Heroku KB: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
|

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Then it should collect static in the right folder. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks it allowed me to deploy.
I know have an error that I can't identify yet but at least it is deployed :)
However now it says that the app can't be found, either when I do heroku open or logs

Answer (score 1):

Please use [whitenoise](https://pypi.org/project/whitenoise/) to deploy static files on heroku.